# Stalled Yeast Stirred

Tags: fermentation

I stirred what I thought was a stalled yeast and I think I stirred too hard.  What are the down falls of introducing oxygen after the fermentation?

Answer (score 6):

You have the potential for oxidized beer.  It may not happen, or if it does it may not be too bad.  But the best thing to do would be to drink the beer soon, before potential oxidation has a chance to get worse.

Comment: Oxidation can add a stale, paper or cardboard flavour and in some beers it increases the caramel flavour. Old Ales require a bit of oxidation.